# setInterval doesn't work when use jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, setinterval

I use jquery mobile build a alarm project, i created two page in my index.html, when i click `Add Alarm` button, the dialog page show up, then i can set the alarm date and time, I want to use `setInterval` to trigger alarm when i click `save` button.

But in found that, the function in `setInterval` doesn't work. How could this happen?

Below is my html file:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Share Alarm</h1>
        <a href="#addNewAlarm" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="plus">Add Alarm</a>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview">
      ...
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="addNewAlarm">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>New Alarm</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="setAlarm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input id="alarmTitle" type="text" placeholder="title" data-inline="true"/>
                <input id="alarmDate" type="date" data-role="datebox" name="alarmdate"
                       data-options='{"mode":"calbox","useFocus": true, "useNewStyle":true}' class="ui-icon-datebox"
                       readonly/>
                <input id="alarmTime" type="datetime" data-inline="true" data-role="datebox"
                       data-options='{"mode":"timeflipbox","useFocus": true, "useNewStyle":true}'
                       class="ui-icon-datebox"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" id="saveAlarm"/>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and this is my js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#saveAlarm").click(function () {

            var deStr = $("#alarmDate").datebox('getTheDate').toLocaleDateString();
            var dtStr = $("#alarmTime").datebox('getTheDate').toTimeString();
            setTimer($("#alarmTitle").val(),deStr,dtStr);
            setInterval(function(){alert(1111);},1000);
            alert(123);
        });
    });
    function setTimer(title,dateStr,timeStr) {
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            var now=new Date();
            console.log(now.toTimeString());
            if(now.toLocaleDateString() == dateStr && now.toTimeString() == timeStr){
                alert("Alarm "+title+"has gone off !");
//                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        },1000);
        return timer;
    }
```

Both two setInterval function didn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile automatically enhances pages by registering its functions to handle the jQuery ready. If you want to include custom JavaScript
in a document, you have to take care not to have your code executed before jQuery Mobile has finished
processing the document. This means you have to wait for a different event, called `pageinit`

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function() {
   //Your code.
});
```

Or you could try delegated event:

```
$(document).on("click","#saveAlarm",function () {
            var deStr = $("#alarmDate").datebox('getTheDate').toLocaleDateString();
            var dtStr = $("#alarmTime").datebox('getTheDate').toTimeString();
            setTimer($("#alarmTitle").val(),deStr,dtStr);
            setInterval(function(){alert(1111);},1000);
            alert(123);
        });
```

Comment: I have changed $(document).ready to your code, but it still didn't work. my question is why the function in setInterval never run ?

Comment: @Jack Zhang: the problem is when you call `$("#saveAlarm").click`, the `saveAlarm` may not available yet because jQuery mobile has not finished processing and there is no event handler attached.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out, Same like @Khanh TO commented, i used below js code instead of my original one, and it works well now.

```
var timer=[],timerId,deStr,dtStr;
$(document).on("pagehide", "#addNewAlarm", function () {
        $("#saveAlarm").click(function () {
            deStr = $("#alarmDate").datebox('getTheDate').toLocaleDateString();
            dtStr = $("#alarmTime").datebox('getTheDate').toTimeString().substring(0, 5);
            if ($.inArray(timerId,timer) == -1) {
                setTimer($("#alarmTitle").val(),deStr,dtStr);
                timer.push(timerId);
            }
        });
    });

    function setTimer(title, dateStr, timeStr) {
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            var now = new Date();
            console.log(now.toTimeString());
            if (now.toLocaleDateString() == dateStr && now.toTimeString().substring(0, 5) == timeStr) {
                alert("Alarm " + title + "has gone off !");
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 1000);
        return timer;
    }
```

Comment: I think `$("#saveAlarm").click` will be called multiple times (everytime when the event `pagehide` fires). This will cause problems.

Comment: In this case, you could also use delegated event. This guarantees that the event handler is attached only once.